# Llenado de Array

Tags: php, array

Tengo un archivo php que llena un array con una búsqueda en una base de datos, el problema es que quiero hacer que si el array viene vació, llenarlo con datos indicando que no se obtuvieron resultado de la búsqueda. El detalle es que intento validarlo con un "if" pero cuando cuando el array viene lleno, siempre entra al "if". Mandando los datos y también los datos que pongo en el if. Puede que sea sencilla la solución pero no logro dar con ella.
Adjunto código para explicar mejor.

```
<?php
        $hostname="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $database="dbalcaldia";
$json=array();
        if(isset($_GET["nit"])){
        $nit = $_GET["nit"];
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8mb4");
        $consulta = "SELECT nombre, fecha_hora_cobro, nombreImpuestoServicio, descripcion, costo, unidades_cobradas, monto_cobro FROM personas INNER JOIN cobranzas INNER JOIN impuestos INNER JOIN detalle_cobranzas ON personas.id = cobranzas.idusuario AND impuestos.id = detalle_cobranzas.idimpuesto WHERE nit = '{$nit}' GROUP BY cobranzas.id LIMIT 12";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $json['personas'][]=$registro;
        }          

        if ($registro == null){            
            $resultar["nombre"] = 'Sin resultados';
            $resultar["fecha_hora_cobro"] = "Sin resultados";
            $resultar["nombreImpuestoServicio"] = 'Sin resultados';
            $resultar["descripcion"] = 'Sin resultados';
            $resultar["costo"] = 0.0;
            $resultar["unidades_cobradas"] = 0;
            $resultar["monto_cobro"] = 0.0;
            $json['personas'][] = $resultar;
        } 
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

analicemos las lineas con problemas

```
while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
```

Va mandando a $registro los resultados que va obteniendo de resultado, como dice el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Pero dice algo mas, que es justamente lo que te pasa:

> Retorna un array que corresponde a la fila obtenida o NULL si es que
>   no hay más filas en el resultset representado por el parámetro result.

O sea, que siempre al terminar, haya o no registros, va a terminar en null.

Por lo tanto siempre va a agregar lo de la fila vacia.

Tu mejor opcion? no compares contra $registro, ya que al final siempre es null. Fijate si el array $json tiene o no registros, y ahi agrega el vacio o no.

Comment: Gracias, funciona justo como tu dices, gracias bro. Respuesta marcada como correcta.